# Proving sequence is bounded and increasing for Monotone Convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

I have to prove that the sequence $a_{k+1}=\frac{5a_k}{2+a_k}$ with $a_0=1$ is convergent.

I think I can use the Monotone Convergence Theorem for this, but I can't show that it is bounded and convergent inductively.

Comment: Do we know $a_1$?

Comment: Yes, we know $a_0=1$

Comment: Hint: prove $a_k < 3$ for all $k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=\frac5{2+a_k}$ is greater than $1$ when $-2<a_k<3$. Since $a_0=1$, it’s clear that $a_k>0$ for all $k$, so the sequence is increasing as long as $a_k<3$. Suppose that $a_k<3$. Then

$$\frac3{a_{k+1}}=\frac{6+3a_k}{5a_k}=\frac35+\frac6{5a_k}>\frac35+\frac6{15}=1\,,$$

so $a_{k+1}<3$. Thus, the sequence is increasing and bounded above by $3$, so it converges to some $L\le 3$. Now use the recurrence to show that $L=3$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{1}{a_{n+1}}=\dfrac{2+a_n} {5a_n}=\dfrac{2}{5a_n}+\dfrac{1}{5}$$
Let $b_n = \dfrac1{a_n}$.  Then $$b_n = \frac25 b_{n-1} + \frac15$$ with $b_0 = 1$, so
\begin{aligned}
b_n &= \left[\frac15\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(\dfrac25\right)^i \right] + \left(\frac25\right)^n b_0 \\
&= \frac15 \frac{1-(2/5)^n}{1-2/5} + \left(\frac25\right)^n = \frac{1-(2/5)^n}{3} + \left(\frac25\right)^n \\
&= \frac13+\frac23 \left(\frac25\right)^n,
\end{aligned}
thus $\lim_\limits{n \to +\infty} b_n = \dfrac13$, and $\lim_\limits{n \to +\infty} a_n = \dfrac{1}{\lim_\limits{n \to +\infty} b_n} = 3$.

Note: In this approach, it's clear that the initial value $b_0$ has no effect on the final limit, as its coefficient is $(2/5)^n$, which quickly diminishes as $n$ grows large.

Answer (score 0):

We have $a_n > 0$ (by induction).

Moreover, let us prove that $a_n \in (0,3)$ by induction.

$$a_{n+1}  \vee  3$$
$$\frac{5a_n}{2+a_n} \vee 3$$
$$5a_n \vee 6 + 3a_n$$
$$a_n \vee 3$$
$$a_n < 3$$
Hence $a_{n+1} < 3$.

Let us prove that $a_{n+1} > a_n$ by induction.

$$a_{n+1} \vee a_n$$
$$\frac{5a_n}{2+a_n} \vee a_n$$
$$5 \vee 2 + a_n$$
$$5 > 2 + a_n$$
Hence $a_{n+1} > a_n$.

Thus $0 < a_n < a_{n+1} < 3$ and by monotone convergence theorem we get that $a_n$ converges.

It's not hard to show that $a_n \to 3$.

Any questions?

Comment: I suspect that the OP won't understand your notation with $\lor$.

Comment: @RobArthan, I agree with you that there may be a misunderstanding in notation - that's why I proposed to ask any questions.

Comment: I realised I had made a mistake about the limit and edited the comment. Apologies for any confusion.